# Unexpectedly Quit Alert in iPhone sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hockeyapp

When I launch the my app sometimes I am getting the Device Alert as `MyApp Unexpectedly Quit,
Would you like to send report so we can fix the problem?`:

[image]

I have integrated **HockeyApp** for getting crash reports.

Anyone suggest me, how can I resolve this.

Comment: You might be able to salvage this question by supplying the crash report and asking for help in determining why it crashed. You can get the crash report from Xcode Organizer, if I recall correctly. Better, leave this question closed and ask a new question.

Comment: [Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) and [Debugging Deployed iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this your own app, then you integrated the HockeyApp SDK and did not turn off crash reporting. Disable crash reporting and this alert will go away. This won't fix the underlying issue that's causing the crash though.

Comment: So If I disable the crash report my app will get crashed ... right?